# Как реализовывать добавление данных? C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model-view

Положение дел:

Я изучаю MVVM. Если я не ошибаюсь, то Model нужен нам для того, чтобы реализовывать в нём бизнес-логику (сервис), а ViewModel нужен, чтобы сделать при помощи него привязку данных между View и Model.

Сама проблема:

Где реализовать добавление данных в базу данных? В ViewModel или Model?

На данный момент это реализовано в ViewModel:

```
public ICommand AddRoomCommand =>
            _addRoomCommand ??
            (_addRoomCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    Context.Rooms.Add(new Room
                    {
                        Number = RoomInfo.Number,
                        Type = RoomInfo.Type
                    });
                    Context.SaveChanges();
                },
                () =>
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RoomInfo.Number) || RoomInfo.Type == RoomTypes.None)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }));
```

Кстати, вот Model Room:

```
public class Room : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private RoomTypes _type;
        private string _number;
        private int _roomId;
        private IList<Client> _clients;

        public int RoomId
        {
            get => _roomId;
            set
            {
                if (value == _roomId) return;
                _roomId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Number
        {
            get => _number;
            set
            {
                if (value == _number) return;
                _number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public RoomTypes Type
        {
            get => _type;
            set
            {
                if (value == _type) return;
                _type = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public virtual IList<Client> Clients
        {
            get => _clients;
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _clients)) return;
                _clients = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public Room()
        {
            _clients = new List<Client>();
        }
    }
```

Если всё-таки нужно делать это в Model, то, пожалуйста, расскажите как сделать это лучше всего.

Этот проект не мой, я взял его отсюда: https://github.com/mentapro/HotelSystem

Answer (score 1):

`Model` может быть не только бизнес-логикой, но и просто данными. Разделяйте как Вам удобно.

Вот пример работы с БД. Для начала я определил `Model`(Cat) - грубо говоря хранилище данных. Интерфейс `IDataStore<T>` который необходимо будет реализовывать каждому классу для работы с конкретной`Model`.

Наша `Model`:

```
class Cat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Логика для работы с нашей `Model`

```
interface IDataStore<T>
{
    Task<bool> AddItem(T item);
    Task<bool> RemoveItem(int id);
    Task<T> GetItem(int id);
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItems();
    Task<bool> UpdateItem(T item);
}

class CatDataStore<Cat> : IDataStore<Cat>
{
    public async Task<bool> AddItem(Cat item)
    {
        //code     
    }

    public async  Task<Cat> GetItem(int id)
    {
        //code
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Cat>> GetItems()
    {
        //code
    }

    public async Task<bool> RemoveItem(int id)
    {
        //code
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateItem(Cat item)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Определим `BaseViewModel` чтобы не писать во всех `Model` реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged`

````
class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    //Метод будет вызывать OnPropertyChanged для конкретного свойства ViewModel, которое будет забинжено к какому-то UI-элементу во ```View```. 


    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T store, T value, 
                                 [CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(store, value))
            return false;

        store = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(prop);
        return true;
    }
}
````

Теперь можно не париться с реализацией `INotifyPropertyChanged` и просто вызывать метод `SetProperty` для нужных свойств уже у конкретных `ViewModel`

```
class CatViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private CatDataStore<Cat> _store = new CatDataStore<Cat>();
    private string _name;
    
    //Это свойство нужно будет забиндить ко View
    public string Name { get => _name; set => SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    

    public ICommand AddCatCommand
    {
         get 
         {
            return new Command((_) => 
            {
                 Cat cat = new Cat { Name = this.Name }; //можно и без this, это для наглядности.
                 _store.AddItem(cat);
            });
         }
    }
}
```

Класс `Command`:

```
class Command : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public Command(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || CanExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: `return new Command` во-первых уже есть дотнете класс Command, например в Xamarin Forms. Чтобы код стал более универсальным, лучше использовать что-то типа `RelayCommand` или `DelegateCommand` как это делается в большинстве MVVM фреймворков. во-вторых, вы создаете новый экземпляр команды каждый раз, когда происходит обращение к форме, лучше кешировать созданный экземпляр например в приватном поле, а создавать его только один раз. Типа `ICommand AddCatCommand => _addCatCommand ??= new Command(...)`.

Comment: Еще одно: `onChange?.Invoke();` не имеет никакого смысла при наличии `OnPropertyChanged`, предлагаю не загружать реализацию тем, что не обязательно нужно. И еще мелочь `_execute.Invoke(parameter)` = `_execute(parameter)`.

Comment: ```onChange``` имеет другую смысловую нагрузку тут, поэтому он и ```null```.  Я написал в ответе, что туда можно закинуть какую-нибудь проверку или метод, который должен происходить, если свойство изменяется. В целом, можно сделать по другому, просто get сделать чуть побольше, но это уже кому как

Comment: Я вам про то, что есть `PropertyChanged` и на него можно подписаться ровно с таким же успехом. `onChange` выглядит как велосипед, просто по непонятным причинам дублирующий уже существующий функционал.

Comment: У меня в приложении метод `SetProperty` вызывается ну очень часто, и я не за что не стал бы его нагружать лишним вызовом тогда, когда он вообще не нужен. А если мне и приспичило трекать свойство, я проекрасно в нужных местах могу подписаться на `PropertyChanged`, и еще и имя свойства из него узнаю. Вы сами то представьте, что мешает сделать `vm.PropertyChanged += (e) => { if (e.PropertyName == "MyProperty") { ... } }`.

Comment: Ну, Вы правы. Не подумал про то, что если свойств будет много, то и ```onChange?.Invoke()``` будет много, а значит будет и много if-ов, соответственно будет много проверок, и в результате будет лишняя нагрузка. Я примерно так себе представляю всё это дело.

Comment: Никогда не поздно подкорректировать код в ответе, я к этому и клоню.

Comment: @aepot, я вот подумал, чем отличается реализация через подписку на PropertyChanged от моего Action? Это ведь одно и то же. Когда будет вызываться PropertyChanged, то будет и вызываться метод ```+= (e) => { if(e.PropertyName == "MyProperty")}```, который так же будет нагружать своим существованием т.к блок кода внутри if будет постоянно проверяться при каждом вызове SetProperty, т.е аналогично с моим Action. Только тут проверка ```PropertyName```, а у меня по ```null```